# Android create own pdf reader

Tags: android, pdf, pdf-reader

i wrote code witch can to open pdf file in sdcard.but My question is there any possiblities to view Pdf files in own Layout using Xml files not static into Java files
this is a my  code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            File pdfFile = new File(Environment
                    .getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test.pdf");

            try {
                if (pdfFile.exists()) {
                    Uri path = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile);
                    Intent objIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    objIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
                    objIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(objIntent);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File NotFound",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "No Viewer Application Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

}

and also i have second question
2) when i run project on my device i have like this screen (

[image]) when i click menu button on my device then i can to show setting menu
it is a possible to create my own menu.for example i want to create my button witch can to zoom same as a static menu's zoom button
thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
use webview in different layout in  our application like this::---->


webview.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>

main.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonUrl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Go to http://www.google.com" />

</LinearLayout>


mainactivity.java 

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button button;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Context context = this;

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUrl);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebViewActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("url","www.google.com")
            startActivity(intent);
          }

        });

    }

}


webviewactivity.java

public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                if (getIntent().hasExtra("url")) {
                    webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
                }


    }

}
```

Comment: meybe you did not understand me . i want to create only own pdf reader.i read that it is not possible to show pdf file from sdcard in webview

Comment: https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview  , https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library

Comment: i downloaded this project and library contains errors on eclipse :(